# Sharing curl handler among gearman workers

Tags: php, curl, gearman

I've a gearman worker (called "manager") which reads a list of urls and then calls, for each of them, another gearman worker (called "dependent") which fetches the content of passed url and does some work on it - indexing, and so on. Each url belongs to the same domain (eg: www.test.com). When every worker calls the `curl_init()`, a new connection is made to www.test.com.

I'm looking to a method to share the curl's resource handler among workers in order to reuse the same connection. In my case the *manager* could create the resource handler, then pass it to *dependents* as a workload parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared memory for store a variable with semaphore functions, http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php.

Or you can use APC, and dump cached variables into file. But I'am not sure how it will works.

Comment: Ofcourse, it doesn't work if your workers placed at different servers

Comment: Could I use a centralized redis store? Redis could hold something as:

<gearman_server_ip:target_domain:resource_id>

Comment: What for? And why you want to share cURL resourse instead of to create new?